# Copy of Welcome Message in Magento?

Tags: email, magento, message

I need to receive a copy of the email Welcome customers (Magento 1.7), how do it?
I think it's here: Customer account form block.
But, i do not know how to do.

Thanks!!

Comment: Try also posting this to http://magento.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Register in magento and wait for email :)

Or (if you want only see how it looks like) go to System->Transactional Emails
Press "Add new template" button and chose Template "New Account". Then "Load template" button and now You can view template by pressing "Preview Template" button on top right.
Amen

Comment: Hi Friend, thanks for reply.
I have a store, and i need to receive a copy of the welcome message, with the e-mail and password for each new customer.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with this. User passwords should be known only for users. Why do You want to know user passwords?

Comment: when shopping in my store, an account in posting service is created, with the same password. The accompanying posting service will be monitored by us, so I need the password.